# How do i fix a image overlapping my header shadow?

Tags: html, css

Im using unbounce.com and created a shadow with the custom CSS option. The image from the section underneath is overlapping the shadow from the header element. What do I need to do to change this issue?

[image: Here you can see the problem]

this is the code im using to create the shadow:

```
#lp-pom-block-11-color-overlay {
        -webkit-box-shadow:
          0 0.063rem 0.313rem rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 
          0 0.188rem 0.25rem rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 
          0 0.125rem 0.25rem rgba(0,0,0,0.14)
  }
```

Comment: please include all html and css relating to this problem

Comment: If z-index does help you with it then you have to add your HTML & CSS for further help.

Comment: Did you try adding z-index to this element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `z-index` value of `#lp-pom-block-11-color-overlay` bigger than below div. `z-index` property always work with `position` except `static`

```css
#lp-pom-block-11-color-overlay {
        -webkit-box-shadow:
          0 0.063rem 0.313rem rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 
          0 0.188rem 0.25rem rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 
          0 0.125rem 0.25rem rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
          position: relative;
          z-index: 9;
  }
```

Comment: @Amarjit Singh before provide a same answer try enhancing the answer will help everyone.

Comment: @SumitPatel I already did, your answer is not much clear and link takes to `position:absolute` property which may lead to distort design. So please answer carefully. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Use `z-index` property to stack them to get over the overlapping issue.

[More Info](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: @SumitPatel It  will better when you provide snippet with working demo., This will increase the chance of accepting your answer

Comment: @KareemDabbeet i agree but there is no code can't create any snippet for that i already add the comment :).